# Allow SPA client using client credential grant token and personal access token - Laravel Passport

Tags: javascript, laravel, oauth, laravel-passport

I'll put them in context first.

I am developing a Rest API using laravel and as an oauth2 authorization method using Laravel Passport as an implementation.

On the other hand I am developing a Javascript client (Single Page Application or SPA) that will consume the API Rest.

The situation is as follows:

Some API Rest endpoints must always be accessible by the client (a valid client since the API is not public) and other endpoints must only be accessible by the client when a user is logged in.

In a first approach what has been proposed is that when the SPA is initially opened in the browser, you get a **Client Credential Grant Token** so that it is a valid client and can make requests to the "Basic" endpoints of the API. Later, when a user logs in, a **Personal Access Token** will be generated which will allow the client to make requests to all endpoints of the API Rest.

I'm a little confused as to how to put this into practice.

I hope, please, you can help me.

Comment: Where are you confused? When you hit your SPA's URI... you will hit a Laravel route... this route will serve your SPA's home page if you will... You can authenticate your user, establish session... then CSRF protection is basically baked into Laravel...

Comment: hi serge, efectly the spa get a token if a user login and this token will be type personal access token that allow to the spa client sent request to endpoints protected but initially when spa is renderized the point is that must get a client credential token that allow to the client send request to endpoints less restrictives.

It should be noted that api rest has endpoints protected with client credentials middleware and has other endpoints protected with oaut:api middleware.